# How to disable inbound queue calls when on an outbound call using RingCentral?

Tags: ringcentral, call-queue

I have users in a RingCentral call queue. The call queue works well for inbound calls but if a user makes an outbound call, they will still receive inbound queue calls while they are on the outbound call.

How can I disable inbound queue calls when the user makes an outbound call?

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify if the user logins multiple devices (soft-phone, and desk phone) at the same time?